# Bloomberg API: How to check wether connection works?

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I am implementing a tool which relies on Bloombergs blpapilib2, which is the Bloomberg API COM Lib 3.5.

Before giving my user access to any refresh-data functionality, I want to make sure that the connection works. My approach so far:

1. Check wether the library is available and linked. Basically a loop through references does the job.
2. Open a connection with session.Start() . I was hoping to get an error here, but it won't give me one. Thus, step 3.
3. Request some data and verify it (make sure its not empty)

Surporisingly, I cannot reliably reproduce getting an empty result. I expected my session relies on a user being looged into the terminal. It seems I was wrong; even if I log out, my request will be handled and return correct data.

I can imagine two scenarios:

- some background caching in the bbcom-Server
- an alternative authentication method is used

---

I have two questions:

Q1. What is the best way to make sure a user will be able to download data?

Q2. How can I verify whether a connection has been established successfully and a user is authenticated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "cut" the connection, you need to log out and log in on a different machine. If you simply log out the feed is still available using the API.

This is how I test the connection - I think it works fairly well. I have a `BloombergWrapper` class that handles all the low level stuff of communicating with the API and it has the following functions:

```
Private pSession As blpapicomLib2.Session
Private pService As blpapicomLib2.Service

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

  Dim locStatusBar As Variant
  Dim locBbResult As Variant

  On Error GoTo error_handler

  If Application.StatusBar = False Then locStatusBar = False Else locStatusBar = Application.StatusBar
  Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to Bloomberg..."

  Set pSession = New blpapicomLib2.session
  pSession.Start

  pSession.OpenService ("//blp/refdata")
  Set pService = pSession.getService("//blp/refdata")

  Application.StatusBar = locStatusBar
  Exit Sub

error_handler:
  If InStr(Err.Description, "timeout") Then
    Call MsgBox("A Bloomberg timeout has occured. Make sure you are logged on your terminal.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Bloomberg error...")
  End If
  If locStatusBar <> "" Then Application.StatusBar = locStatusBar

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  pSession.Stop
  Set pSession = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot like what I'm looking for. For some reason, `On Error GoTo errHandler´ does not catch a runtime error I get: "Runtime error -2147024809 (80070057): Service '//blp/refdata' not found". Why's that? (The Lib is linked, and BB is NOT running, and has never been running on this machine, but is installed.) Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick update, I had the debugger halt on all errors, including those that where handled, rendering any error-handling pointless ;) This solution works perfectly fine. Thanks!